# Tomcat 7 automatic crashed after adding a web application

Tags: tomcat, jvm

I am trying to run my web application under tomcat7 with ubuntu 11.10.  And I reset the port to 80 by using authbind. And it is working well when there is no app added to the /webapps/ folder. For example, I can access example.com to the tomcat default start page.

Then I tried to add my web application into the webapps/ folder and restarted the server. Afterwards, I can not visit both the default page or my web apps. I checked the tomcat process and found that the server is stopped a while after I tried to access the pages(no matter the tomcat default page or my app).

There are some details about my app, the package is about 70MB and using large memory to initialize many objects for the app. I guess it is because of the JVM crash, but I have no idea how to locate the issue.

Comment: Please post your catalina.out log, located in the logs subdir of Tomcat.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. My app needs some config files on the root drive which I forgot to add it. I check the log and found my fault.

Comment: Kyleinincubator, I have the same problem, can you please post your solution here? what are the config files on the root drive that you have to add?

Comment: @Rami The reason why it did not work for me was that I forgot some configs for my apps in the root folder and it does work after I copied the files into the root and it works.

Comment: Hi kyleinincubator, do you remember what the configs that you forgot? thank you

Comment: @Rami they are some files related to my applications, I need store some parameters for my app there. I was trying to move my app to a new server so that was the reason I forgot those files.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that my machine was very limited in term of RAM memory (A free tire AWS server). It is not stable if we keep on deploying and un-deploying applications from it. Now I moved to a paid version and everything seems to be fine. Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Yes, when I used a mini instance of AWS EC2, I often got the out of memory exception.